# How to set request attribute in free marker template

Tags: java, javascript, freemarker

I am developing spring batch web application in java that uses SPRING MVC. It uses free marker templates.
I need to set userid in request attribute in javascript written on FTL page.
I am using below javascript to retrieve username. I want to set(WinNetwork.UserName) it in request attribute and want to retrieve this attribute on my servlet.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     var WinNetwork = new  ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
     alert(WinNetwork.UserName); 
</script>
```

Please provide help on this.

Comment: do you know this code will only work in IE?

Comment: I suspect you didn't realize that JavaScript (in this case) runs on the client, and FreeMarker always runs on the server. So if you want to do it with JavaScript, then FreeMarker is irrelevant.